# Log4net is not logging

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a small console application, which refers to a library project. I am trying to log possible errors using log4net. It works when I call e.g. `Log.Debug(myErrorMsg)` from the main project, but when I try to do the same from the library project, it writes nothing. Could you please tell what can cause this?

In my app.config:

```xml
<configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
</configSections>
<log4net>
    <root>
       <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="LogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="C:\MyProject\bin\Debug\log.txt" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p%d{yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss} – %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

In my main():

```
XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

In my dll project:

```
internal static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(FileWatcherLogic));
```

...

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var msg = string.Format("Error handling file {0}: {1}", fullPath, ex.Message);
    Console.Write(msg);
    Log.Error(msg);
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're missing the `<level>` element in your `<root>` declaration to tell log4net which log levels to actually log.

Does changing your current root to this fix your problem?

```xml
<root>
   <level value="ALL" /> <!-- or "DEBUG", "WARN", "INFO", etc -->
   <appender-ref ref="LogFileAppender" />
</root>
```

Alternatively, if that doesn't work - you can add this key to your app or web.config in your `<appSettings>` to get verbose debugging information written to the console by log4net to tell you exactly what is wrong:

```xml
<add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
```

Comment: No, unfortunately, it didn't help.

Comment: @DavidShochet try adding the key above i just added to my question and re-run your program. you should see exactly why log4net is failing to load correctly.

Comment: Thanks. Due to this debugging feature, I figured out that log4net was conflicting with NServiceBus.